# Remove trailing slashes from store URL's - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, url, store-view, store-switcher

We set the "Add Store Code to URLs" option to Yes, so now our store URL's looks like:

```
https://www.example.com/en/
https://www.example.com/de/
https://www.example.com/fr/
```

And by default Magento redirects the url without the last slash to the url with a slash.
So `https://www.example.com/en` redirects to `https://www.example.com/en/`

How can we disable this?
We want to transform our urls into:

```
https://www.example.com/en
https://www.example.com/de
https://www.example.com/fr
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the URL redirect from a URL without a trailing slash to a URL with a trailing slash, you can follow these steps:

1. Login to your Magento 2 admin panel.
2. Go to Stores > Configuration.
   Expand the General section and click on Web.
3. Open the Url Options section.
   Set the Auto-redirect to Base URL option to No.
4. Click on the Save Config button to save your changes.

After disabling this option, Magento will no longer redirect the URL without a trailing slash to the URL with a trailing slash. Your URLs will look like this:

> https://www.example.com/en
>
> https://www.example.com/de
>
> https://www.example.com/fr

Please note that disabling this option may cause issues with duplicate content and affect your SEO. If you are unsure about the implications of disabling this option, you may want to consult with a SEO expert before making any changes.

Comment: Thanks Navneet! We do know this option, but the problem in that case is that it will never redirect and we indeed get duplicate content issues. Because it also does not redirect `https://www.example.com/en/` to `https://www.example.com/en` in that case and we want to keep this behavior. So we only would like to remove the last `/` trailing slash

Comment: then did you try to do using htaccess ?